# Adding product data to processing email for WP WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I have looked and looked and I cannot figure out how to get this working.

I am using the request a quote plugin for wp woocommerce and I am trying to set the email up so that the email that gets sent to the customer has the product info in it. (description, attributes, images). Right now all it is sending is the Product Name - Price Quoted.

Here is the email template that is currently being used.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="order-table-heading" style="text-align:left; padding: 12px 0 6px;">
                        <span class="highlight">
                            <?php echo __( 'Order Number:', 'email-control' ) ?>
                        </span> 
                        <?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="order-table-heading" style="text-align:right; padding: 12px 0 6px;">
                        <span class="highlight">
                            <?php echo __( 'Order Date:', 'email-control' ) ?>
                        </span> 
                        <?php printf( '<time datetime="%s">%s</time>', date_i18n( 'c', strtotime( $order->order_date ) ), date_i18n( wc_date_format(), strtotime( $order->order_date ) ) ); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="order_items_table" border="0" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" class="order_items_table_th_style order_items_table_td order_items_table_td_left order_items_table_th_bg_color order_items_table_td_top"><?php _e( 'Product', 'email-control' ); ?></th>
                        <th scope="col" class="order_items_table_th_style order_items_table_td order_items_table_th_bg_color order_items_table_td_top"><?php _e( 'Quantity', 'email-control' ); ?></th>
                        <th scope="col" class="order_items_table_th_style order_items_table_td order_items_table_td_right order_items_table_th_bg_color order_items_table_td_top" style="text-align:right"><?php _e( 'Price', 'email-control' ); ?></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php echo $order->email_order_items_table( $order->is_download_permitted(), true, ( $order->status=='processing' ) ? true : false ); ?>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <?php
                    if ( $totals = $order->get_order_item_totals() ) {
                        $i = 0;
                        foreach ( $totals as $total ) {
                            $i++;
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row" colspan="2" class="order_items_table_totals_style order_items_table_td order_items_table_td_left order_items_table_th_bg_color">
                                    <?php echo $total['label']; ?>
                                </th>
                                <td class="order_items_table_totals_style order_items_table_td order_items_table_td_right order_items_table_th_bg_color" style="text-align:right;" >
                                    <?php echo $total['value']; ?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
```

Here is the output of that
[image]

If anyone can help me figure this out I would appreciate it so much. Like I said, I have looked everywhere and I cannot find how to bring the product info into the outgoing email.

Let me say I have also tried the plugins Pretty emails and Email customizer and I couldn't get those to do what I need.

Wanted to add what I need the end result to look like. This is an example email that is pulling the data from php/mysql but I can't figure out how to get it to work with wp and woocommerce.
http://s29.postimg.org/85gnobkmv/quote_image.jpg